# AngularFire docData read value once

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

What is the correct way to read the content of a document as value without subscription ?
Keep in mind that when persistence is enabled the Observer receives two values, first value is the locally persisted one and the second is the actual value that is stored in the database.

Comment: I shared my solution below. can you let me know whether it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) method to retrieve the contents of a single document.

For More details you can check this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211249/18265570)